# How to automatically retweet a twitter page?

Tags: java, python, python-2.7, twitter, twitter4j

How to automate the task of retweetsof a page: **twitter.com/promotional/sample_page** in such a way that whenever there is tweet posted on twitter from that page then the automated script retweeted from my twitter account **twitter.com/demo-account/** .
Can it be implemented using python or java?
Following the attached link:

http://www.techcovered.org/how-to-create-your-own-twitter-auto-retweet-bot/

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You seem to be asking for someone to write some code for you. Stack Overflow is a question and answer site, not a code-writing service. Please [see here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to learn how to write effective questions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can easily do this in python using [TwitterAPI](https://github.com/geduldig/TwitterAPI).

The steps are basically:

1. Authenticate

> from TwitterAPI import TwitterAPI api = TwitterAPI(consumer_key,
> consumer_secret, access_token_key, access_token_secret)

2. Grab the tweet you want to retweet
3. Tweet it

> x = api.request('statuses/update', {'status': *the tweets text*})
>
> print(x.status_code)

It is quite straight forward, I won't spoil it for you posting the full working code.

Comment: thanks,can you tell me how to get those security credentials because I am new to the job?

Comment: @anoop Take a look at https://dev.twitter.com/oauth, there you shall find the answer.

Comment: thanks,for sharing.. :)

Comment: @anoop if you consider my answer helpful enough, can you mark it as right?

Comment: your answer helps me a lot,but still I am unable to implement retweet feature using twitterAPI because there is no support for **statuses/retweets** in it.. :(

Comment: @anoop It is supported. Use this: `r = api.request('statuses/retweets/:%d' % TWEET_ID)`

Comment: @jonas, thanks man!! ,it works.. :)